# why is Javascript google docs app script try statement running only one statement if

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

why does in the example 1 the console log is executed while in example 2 it's not executed ?

```
//Example 1
try {
    console.log("Trying to connect");
    google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler( function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
    .sendText(data);
} catch {
    console.log("No connection");
}
```

---

```
//Example 2
try {
    google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler( function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
    .sendText(data);
    console.log("Trying to connect");
} catch {
    console.log("No connection");
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which `console.log`? unclear.

Comment: ups sorry mate did not saw that someone wrote something here. From the outside oh the thread/topic it's not possible to see that kind of reply it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your question is about the `Trying to connect` message.

When an error happens in a `try` block, the rest of the code in the block is skipped, and it goes to the `catch` block instead.

In both examples, you're getting an error in `google.script.run()`. In example 1, you log the message before the error, so the log message is shown, then it goes to the `catch` block. In example 2, you get the error before you log the message, so it goes directly to the `catch` block and skips the `console.log("Trying to connect");` line.

Comment: Yehh it was that indeed my question. Tought the message would be not block even if it comes after the error. Thanks for the answer and a fast one.

Comment: `google.script.run` is async client-server communication. Any error in the server function is ignored by the example code here. Why do you think it is throwing an error?

Comment: @tehhowch If it's not throwing an error, the `console.log()` would be executed. If it's not connected, that may throw an error synchronously.

Comment: Well in this particular case it's trowing because i am running the web page outside of the google api at my home to test the page it self not the javascript and i noted the message was not being printed . Them i try to place the message before the google command and it printed .